# Asp.net and Vex jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on  a Gridview in Asp.net C# that Deletes a row from the Sql Server Database using the RowCommandEvent and I want to prompt the user first a confirm box created in Vex jQuery(vex.dialog.confirm) before deleting a row. If The user clicks "Yes" the the RowCommadEvent in Gridview will be executed... Could you please help me achieve this...Thanks in advance! Below are my codes....

My Vex jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function DeleteRows() {
            vex.dialog.confirm({
                message: 'Are you sure to delete this record?',
                callback: function(value) {
                    if (value) {

                      // I want to callthe RowCommandEvent here...
                    }
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Asp.net Page Source that triggers the deleting of row

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="img_delete" runat="server" Height="16px"CommandName="DeleteRow"               ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" Width="16px" CausesValidation="False" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("OrgID") %>' OnClientClick="return DeleteRows();" ToolTip="Delete" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Asp.net C# CodeBehind

```
protected void gv_Organization_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "DeleteRow" && confirmDelete.Value == "True")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "vex.dialog.alert", "vex.dialog.alert('" + confirmDelete.Value + "');", true);

            try
            {

                Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                using (OrganizationDataContext odc = new OrganizationDataContext())
                {

                    Organization org = odc.Organizations.SingleOrDefault(o => o.OrgID.Equals(id));
                    odc.Organizations.DeleteOnSubmit(org);
                    odc.SubmitChanges();
                    gv_Organization.DataBind();
                }
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "notification", "notification('Information', 'Organization is <strong>successfully</strong> deleted.');", true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "notification", "notification('error', 'Organization is ID <strong>NOT DELETED</strong>.');", true);

            }
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
        {
            try
            {

                Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                using (OrganizationDataContext odc = new OrganizationDataContext())
                {
                    Organization org = odc.Organizations.SingleOrDefault(o => o.OrgID.Equals(id));
                    LoadOrgInfo(org);

                    btn_save.Text = "Update";

                    /*org.OrgID = int.Parse(tb_orgID.Text);
                    org.OrgName = tb_orgName.Text;
                    org.OrgType = ddl_type.SelectedValue;
                    odc.SubmitChanges();
                    DisplayOrganization();*/
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "notification", "notification('error', 'Organization is ID <strong>NOT UPDATED</strong>.');", true);

            }
        }
    }
```